# xjc mixed content generated as List<Object> instead of List<Serializable>

Tags: xsd, jaxb, websphere, wsdl2java, xjc

I am trying to re-generate web  service stubs and java objects from WSDL and XSD's using the batch commands available in WAS 7 (wsdl2java.bat, using ant script).

In the generated file, the field denoting mixed content is displayed as:

```
@XmlMixed
protected List<Object> content;
```

However, my existing codebase has the following:

```
@XmlMixed
protected List<Serializable> content;
```

Due to this issue, I am getting compilation errors. I am using JDK 1.6. 
The schema has not change in between. It would be great if you could advise me on how to make sure the generated code confirms to `Serializable` type instead of object.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-extension` when generating JAXB classes and check. Like below.

```
xjc -extension schema.xsd
```